# models.py in sqlalchemy forces class relationships to be above the class being referenced

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My python classes are being forced to be defined in my models.py above the classes trying to use them. This is fine except I have some bi-directional relationships I can not form because they reference each other.

models.py

```
class Language(Updateable, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'language'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    language = sqla.Column(sqla.String(2), nullable=False)

    type_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey(Type.id), index=True)
    type = sqla_orm.relationship('Type', back_populates='translated_languages')

    #This will complain that 'Type' was not defined prior to this class
    types = sqla_orm.relationship('Type', back_populates='language', UserList=False)


class Type(Updateable, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'type'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)

    translated_languages = sqla_orm.relationship('Language', back_populates='type')

    language_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey(Language.id), index=True)
    language = sqla_orm.relationship('Language', back_populates='types')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `ForeignKey` instances; usually they are referenced as  *tables*, not models, and are passed as strings, as the tables may not yet exist, or may not yet be mapped to the model class.  Also, the relationship keyword argument `UserList` should be `uselist`.

```py
class Language(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'language'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    language = sqla.Column(sqla.String(2), nullable=False)

    type_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('type.id'), index=True)
    type = sqla_orm.relationship('Type', back_populates='translated_languages')

    # This will complain that 'Type' was not defined prior to this class
    types = sqla_orm.relationship('Type', back_populates='language', uselist=False)


class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'type'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)

    translated_languages = sqla_orm.relationship('Language', back_populates='type')

    language_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('language.id'), index=True)
    language = sqla_orm.relationship('Language', back_populates='types')
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I was trying to figure out why some were strings vs models. I feel dumb now haha.